# UILocalNotification without alert

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

Is it possible to to call `didReceiveLocalNotification` without displaying Alert when in background?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`didReceiveLocalNotification` will only be called if you app is in the foreground or when the user clicked to view the notification and you app is restored to the foreground from the background.

You might be able to use a `UILocalNotification` with out a message, by example update your application icon badge. But then the `didReceiveLocalNotification` will not be called if you apps in not the in foreground.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way sadly, `UILocalNotication` has been designed to notify the user with an alert view, thats how apple intended them to work

You could set `notification.alertBody` to nil, but then you will not be able to use this local notification when the application is not active